# Bullet proofing a server with 150 WP insallations

Tags: plugins, themes, security, installation

We have about 150 active blogs we are serving our clients and the maintenance is getting to the point where it's not going to be profitable.  In order to save space and maint costs, I've symlinked the `plugins` and `themes` -- That way I can have one code base and keep them up to date acting like a "single installation".

Each installation has of course it's own DB and unique user that can only access said DB via GRANT.  The problem is with the plugins and themes being a symlink, if one gets infected with malware, they all get infected, and in turn all 150 WP installs are instantly compromised.

Is there a safer way to do what I am accomplishing?  Separating it all out into say docker containers, means upgrading plugins one at a time and same with themes.

There has to be others out there struggling with this concept, but I haven't found anything concrete yet!

Is there a proven method to accomplish what I am trying to do without putting the entire server at risk of being overrun when a single site gets compromised?

Comment: Plugins can be set to auto-update on their own, especially if there isn't any tricky functionality likely to break with updates. There are also paid services out there where you can manage theme and plugin updates universally - that way you actually have them installed separately, so they're separate targets, but you also can manage the updates centrally and not spend so much time taking care of them. The other thing you could look into is managed hosting.

Comment: Have you looked into Multisite?